# Why there are so little snaps in Ubuntu core? Did it stop developing?

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I have just installed Ubuntu Core in my Raspberry Pi 3, and trying to install some basic apps on it. However, when I did type some snap commands, there was nothing much for me to do. What is happening? I thought it (snap store) is well developing?

Could you please give me some instructions or explanation if I did something wrong. Thanks so much.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh heavens no, it's being heavily developed and used!

Note that `snap find` only returns a few snaps when given no argument, otherwise the results would be impossible to parse. You can `snap find` specific things though. For example:

```
$ snap find kyrofa
Name                   Version     Developer  Notes   Summary
duckdns-kyrofa         0.1         kyrofa     -       Keep your DuckDNS records up-to-date
ros2-example-kyrofa    0.1         kyrofa     -       ROS2 Example
pc-turtlebot-kyrofa    16.04-0.8   kyrofa     gadget  AMD64 gadget for the Turtlebot 2
turtlebot-demo-kyrofa  0.2         kyrofa     -       Turtlebot ROS Demo
darktable-kyrofa       2.2.5snap2  kyrofa     -       Virtual lighttable and darkroom for photographers
```

As popey notes in the comments, search results are returned depending on the architecture of your host. If you're running amd64, `snap find` will only return amd64 snaps, etc. Some developers only release snaps for amd64, and those won't be found on a Raspberry Pi, for example.

Comment: So, how can I know the list of current available packages for installing? Thanks

Comment: Just search for what you're looking for! There is also an unofficial online interface at https://uappexplorer.com that you can try.

Comment: Thanks so much for your info. I'm looking for mongodb and parse to install, however they haven't got. Might be I have to wait for some time until they're developed

Comment: Worth noting some developers are only uploading amd64 and i386 packages, and not armhf ones. We provide a free build service at build.snapcraft.io but not everyone uses it.